# Mongoengine get latest()

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

In django how to get latest instance of a query set if i'm using MongoEngine

Normally  we do

```
Users.objects.latest('id')
```

But i cant use `latest` in MongoEngine.

;) . i'm in stuck .

I didn't find a solution here . but i've implemented . whats your opinion about below

```
Users.objects.all().order_by('-id').limit(1)[0]
```

This will return the latest instance .

and also fixed the issue by committing it to mongoenngine.

https://github.com/anishmenon/mongoengine/

You may install this and use

```
 Users.objects.latest('id')
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do:

```
Users.objects.order_by('-id').first()
```

Answer (score 6):

Ross's answer is great enough.

But if you really need a `latest()`, implementing a custom QuerySet can do this.

**"Decorator" way:**

```
class Users(Document):
    username = StringField()

    @queryset_manager
    def latest(doc_cls, queryset):
        return queryset.order_by('-id').first()
```

**"meta" way:**

```
class UsersQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def latest(self):
        return self.order_by('-id').first()

class Users(Document):
    meta = {'queryset_class': UsersQuerySet}
```

Now you can:

```
Users.objects.latest()
# or
Users.latest()
```